# How do you have multiple javascript libraries in Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: jquery, dynamics-crm, javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

Right I am creating a method which adds an Account to Dynamics CRM with an Ajax POST to a built in webservice, the code is as follows :

```
var context = GetGlobalContext();
var serverUrl = context.getServerUrl();
var ODATA_ENDPOINT = "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc";

var account = new Object();
account.Name = "Sample Account created via OData jQuery library.";

// Parse the entity object into JSON
var jsonEntity = window.JSON.stringify(account);

// Asynchronous AJAX function to Create a CRM record using OData
$.ajax({ type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    datatype: "json",
    url: serverUrl + ODATA_ENDPOINT + "/AccountSet",
    data: jsonEntity,
    beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
        //Specifying this header ensures that the results will be returned as JSON.
        XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    },
    success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) { },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { }
});
```

Right this code has a link to JSON and JQuery libraries, how do i link them in dynamic CRM 2011.

I am looking to execute the code on a onload function to add the new account. But am in the dark at the moment to how that will work.

I understand I have to first:

- Go to web resources
- Add the above jquery
- save the file
- Go to my entity and add the javascript library and its method to call on the onload

but it links to json and jquery libraries though. How does this work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just upload those libraries as additional Web Resources. On the customizations for the form, you can choose which libraries get loaded on the form. Just make sure your JSON and jQuery libraries are loaded before your custom code, and you should be fine.

Comment: When this sort of function is being performed from a SubGrid ribbon button click (ie. could have multiple parent forms), then would it be required to add these form scripts into ALL the parent entity forms that might host this subgrid ribbon? Is there another way to go about it?

Comment: In this instance, you can add all the libraries to the Ribbon XML. For each library, add a <JavaScriptFunction Library="$webresource:webresourceName" FunctionName="isNaN" /> node. It requires a function name, so we've just been putting isNaN in there so there's no error.

Comment: @Matt Matt, could you expand on how to load multiple JS files for a button on the homepage? I tried multiple <JavaScriptFunction.../> nodes as you suggested. No complaints importing the ribbondiff stuff but when I click the button I get a JS fail when it tries to invoke my function in the 2nd JS file. I know my JS is good cause it works on the form ribbon where I can load the 2 files via the form properties. I tried isNaN for the 2nd file def as you suggested. Then I tried my own dummyfunc() with an alert. The alert never gets triggered. Not sure where to go from here...

Comment: @Matt  UPDATE: my 2nd JS file was the JS file that contained the event handler functions for the form. When I removed the ribbon functions and put them into a separate JS file, it now works. Not sure why having my ribbon functions in the same file that contains the form event handlers would be an issue but I'm good to go now.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all other depending JavaScipt libraries are loaded before this javascipt and you have to maintain the depending javascript precedence. Since you are using Json and JQuery libraries you have to load those libaries first. Also if you are using any function of some other library it has to be loaded (it should be in the top of the list) before this javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Use a JS Package/Dependency manager like [Jingo.js](http://code.google.com/p/jingo/)