# How do I use an external Javascript library in CRM Dynamics?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, datajs

I'll be doing some REST-ing and oData-ing so I got the executable from [DataJS project](http://datajs.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=OData%20Code%20Snippets&referringTitle=Using%20OData). I've added the file `datajs-1.0.3.min.js` as a web resource and my own `qwerty.js` as another one. So, I've ended up with two web resources called:

1. CRMKonsulterna_MyOwnStuff
2. CRMKonsulterna_TheCoolStuff

The problem is now that when I execute the code snippet below from web resource 1 that I've found on [their site](http://datajs.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=OData%20Code%20Snippets&referringTitle=Using%20OData), I get a crash telling me that:

Field: window

Event: onload

Error: 'OData' is undefined

```
var shazoo = function () {

  alert("Commenced...");

  OData.read(
    "http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Categories",
    function (data) {
      var html = "";
        $.each(data.results, function (l) { 
          html += "<div>" + l.CategoryName + "</div>";
        });
        $(html).appendTo($("#target-element-id"));
    }
  );

  alert("Completed.");

}
```

How can I refer from a method inside web resource 1 to a method inside web resource 2? I've found [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994083/how-do-you-have-multiple-javascript-libraries-in-dynamics-crm-2011) but it didn't give me much. I can't even tell if it's helpful **if** one understand what they're talking about.

EDIT

I've made some changes and went for trying if `OData` is known to my method like this.

```
alert(OData);
```

Expecting a `null` value, I was surprised to discover that it gave me {Object object} instead. So, I'm guessing the connection between web resources is made. Is it so? Also, still, how can I make the call to get me some oData formatted data?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added **both** libraries to the entity? It's not sufficient to add them only as web resources.

1. Settings -> Solution ->
2. {pick the solution} -> **or** Customizations -> Customize the System ->
3. Components -> Entities -> {pick the entity} -> Forms -> {pick the form type}
4. Form properties -> Form Libraries

Comment: I **had** missed that and your answer **resolved** my problem. Now I've got **an other** error but that's subject to a different question on SO. Thanks!